# How to add Markes to a Leaflet-map with coordinates from database in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, leaflet, google-maps-markers, react-leaflet

I have to display markers for all the places in my database. At the moment I can display just one marker.

I maped over the array from database but I do not know how to connecte these two. I would really appreciate any help.
This is my code so far:

```
<div>
      <MapContainer
        center={position}
        zoom={13}
        scrollWheelZoom={true}
        style={{ height: 500 }}
        // whenCreated={setMap}
        animate={true}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright"'
          url="https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={position}>
          <Popup>Hi there!</Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>

      {places.map((place) => (
        <div key={place.id}>
          {place.longCoord}, {place.latCoord}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

just use .map inside your MapContainer. like below

```
<MapContainer
center={position}
        zoom={13}
        scrollWheelZoom={true}
        style={{ height: 500 }}
        // whenCreated={setMap}
        animate={true}
>
<TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright"'
          url="https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
  {places.map((item, i) => (
    <Marker key={i} position={{ lat: item.latCoord, lng: item.longCoord}}>
      <Popup>Hi there!</Popup>
    </Marker>
  ))}
</MapContainer>;
```